# Nested render in haml

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, renderpartial

In "show.html.haml", I have two renders like this:

```
= render 'project_header', :locals => {@set_tab => "current"}
= render 'project_toolbar'
```

my "_project_header.html.haml" looks like:

```
%article.project
  %header
    %h1.generated
      #some_code
    %h2
      #some_code
```

and my "_project_toolbar.html.haml" looks like:

```
%section.toolbar
   #some_code
```

This end up in html which looks something like:

```
<article class="project">
  #some_code
</article>
<section class="toolbar">
  #some_code
</section>
```

What I want is instead

```
<article class="project">
   #some_code
   <section class="toolbar">
       #some_code
   </section>
</article>
```

I know there can be work around like rendering my "project_toolbar" inside "project_header". But they are two logically independent entities, so I don't want to do it that way.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't see any other way other than rendering `project_toolbar` inside `project_header`.

Comment: You know one another way could be stripping "article" and writing is just before both render. Still, had it been erb, it could have been possible.. isn't haml suppose to be better than erb?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible in haml, one way is

```
%article.project
  = render 'project_header', :locals => {@set_tab => "current"}
  = render 'project_toolbar'
```

or the other ways is, in `_project_header.html.haml`, render `_project_toolbar.html.haml`

```
%article.project
  %header
    %h1.generated
      #some_code
    %h2
      #some_code
  = render 'project_toolbar'
```

Comment: I guess what I am trying to ask is, what would haml equivalent of doing it in erb? In erb we could have just opened article tag in "project_header" and and closed it anywhere we wanted.

Comment: haml closes all tags by it self, so I'm not sure if it's possible to do what you want like in erb, but I think this answer is cleaner anyways.